# Vitest and nuxt 3 form submit testing

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I got a form in a nuxt 3 app with three input fields. Here is how the submit function looks like:

```
const submitForm = async () => {
 try {
      await $fetch("/api/contact", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });
      showForm.value = false;
      successMessage.value =
        "Thank you for your message!<br> Our colleagues will reply to you shortly.";
    } catch (error: any) {
     //error handling
    }
 }
```

Im trying to test the form via Vitest. Im also using "@vue/test-utils" package for mount the component (given values are valid, the form should be submitted):

```
   test("submits form", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Contact);
    const form = wrapper.find("form");

    await form.find("input[name=name]").setValue("dev test");
    await form.find("input[name=email]").setValue("email@dev.hu");
    await form.find("textarea").setValue("some msg");

    await form.get("button").trigger("click");

    await flushPromises();

    expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("Thank you for your message!");
  });
```

All my other tests for validation and stuff are working nicely, but when it comes to submit, i cant get it to work. The test fails, since it cant find the given text, but i dont know why. The problem must be somewhere around the $fetch, if i try to run it without the fetch it works, but not with the $fetch.

Here is the endpoint in `server/api/contact.post.ts`

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  return {
    foo: "ok"
  };
});
```

Am i doing it right? Or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For Vitest you could use Nock, like this

```
test('submits form', async () => {   // Mock the API request   nock('http://localhost')
    .post('/api/contact')
    .reply(200, {
      foo: 'ok',
    })
```

to send you could use

```
await form.get('button').trigger('click')
for sendind,
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
```

Comment: isnt it just doing the same as my server/api/contact.post.ts ?

Comment: I change my answer to do this

Comment: still no success, same effect. it seems like no matter what i do, the $fetch doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging turned out the problem was around the infrastructure (docker container and network stuff), after changing the fetch url to the correct absolute URL

```
await $fetch("http://localhost:80/api/contact", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });
```

the issue resolved.